# Imaginary part of the following complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers

I am completely new to Complex numbers, and having problem with the following sum from my textbook:

If z = –3–i , find Re(z) and Im(z).

I noticed that the above complex number is not in the standard form
i.e.,  a+ib, so I wrote it as  (–3)+(–i*1).

My textbook says Im(z) is –1, why wouldn't it be +1? Or is it that I should write the number as (–3)+(i*–1)?  But then again, the multiplicative identity is always +1, isn't it?

Comment: Check again the definition in your textbook: if $z=a+bi$, then $\Im(z)=b$. Because $z=-3+(-1)i$ we have $-1$ as imaginary part.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression "$-i\cdot1$" is not in the required form "$ib$". For that, you would have to rewrite

$$-i\cdot 1=i\cdot(-1)$$

so then you see that $\operatorname{Im} z$ is indeed $-1$.

(Recall that "$-(x\cdot y)$", "$(-x)\cdot y$", and "$x\cdot(-y)$" all mean the same thing).

Comment: I see, but isn't the multiplicative identity i.e., 1, always +ve, maybe my concept is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. $1$ is the multiplicative identity. That's why you can write $-i$ as $-i\cdot 1$. But how is that relevant? And what do you mean by "+ve" ?

Comment: @MPW "+ve" and "-ve" are somewhat common abbreviations for positive and negative.

Comment: I mean, should i always remain +ve, as we are instead writing it as (i*–1)?

Comment: Yes, if I understand you. In order to be able to correctly read off the real and imaginary parts, you must have a "+" (which may be implicit, like "$7$" means "$+7$") in front of both of them. For example if $w=-2-5i$ then you must think of this as $w=(-2)+(-5)i$, so the real part is $-2$ and the imaginary part is $-5$. If you want to go even further, you can think of complex numbers as being in the form $a\cdot 1 + b\cdot i$, so $1$ is the "real unit" and $i$ is the "imaginary unit"; every complex number is the sum of a unique real multiple of $1$ and a unique real multiple of $i$...

Comment: ... (continued)  The real-number multipliers $a$ and $b$ are the real and imaginary parts of the complex number.

Answer (score 1):

The imaginary part of a complex number is defined to be the (real) coefficient of the imaginary unit $i.$ In this case the real coefficient of $i$ is clearly $-1.$ Thus, $\Im z=-1,$ as your text claims.

Comment: @NoChance This is a well-known definition. It's not private.

Comment: @NoChance I see. It would be nice if you could do that addition. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe including this definition adds value: "A complex number is a number that can be expressed in the form a + bi, where a and b are real numbers, and i is a solution of the equation x2 = −1. Because no real number satisfies this equation, i is called an imaginary number" - Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number